# How to get facebook share count for date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

i have a website where certain pages have a facebook "share" button.
I need to be able to produce a report showing how many times a page has been shared on FB within a give date range. 
Ive had a look at using FQL to query on the Link_Stat table but this only has total counts.

Anyone got any other ideas on how i could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Facebook Insights](https://www.facebook.com/insights/) to easily see this information for your page/app/site. Here is a sample graph I pulled. It allows date range and has other graphs.
[image]

The Facebook Graph API has an [Insights endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) that has some of the data available, although I don't know that it was date range abilities, at least not that I saw documented.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Facebook insights table. Here is the Facebook reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

You will need to use the "Domain Content" metric.